# d3.v3.js makes Dreamweaver crash

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dreamweaver

I've been working with collapsible tree chart using D3 and its working fine. The only problem I am facing is when I include the `d3.v3.min.js` locally, my DreamWeaver CS4 fails to open this file and crashes on the spot.

The code for both the script is like this:

1) From Web

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

2) From local

```
<script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Don't Know what the problem is and I am also executing this code in IIS, the page works very fine in browser, the only concern is that it doesn't opens in Dreamweaver CS4 and crashes it.

Will be happy if somebody can help me out.

Comment: Did you try using Notepad++ or any other text editing tools?

Comment: Yes I tried using Notepad++ and its working fine in that

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but it seems to be limited to the .min version of the file. The unminimized "d3.js" does not cause the crash. I'm developing with the unminimized version and will edit with notepad to .min before production release.

Strange issue. Thought you'd like to know it's not just you. :-)

Comment: I'm literally sitting down to start work on learning D3 and was searching for an IDE when I realized I have Dreamweaver as part of the CC package I have. So I googled Dreamweaver and D3.js and found this... NICE TO KNOW! This should be presented to Adobe! Has anyone posted this bug?

Answer (score 0):

d3 (both minified and not) is also causing my Dreamweaver CS4 to crash.  I don't know the reason, but suspect the logical NOT (!) which starts the d3 code.